# run rails console when i launch docker run

Tags: ruby, docker, containers

actually im working on docker with ruby.
I have a script that i want dockerize, but this script need to be run on rail console for process datas and stay in tunning state for a lot of time.
When i try to dockerize it, container exit with code(0).

this is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruyb:3.2.2
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential
ENV Ruby "/home/user/project_dir"
WORKDIR $RUBY
COPY Gemfile* ./
RUN bundle install
ADD ./home/user/project_dir
CMD ["bundle","exec","ruby","/home/user/project_dir/ruby_app.rb"
```

i tried to run `bundle exec rails c`, it works but it shows me only rails c command line without runnning any file.
I want to automate all then when i try to run `docker run image_name`, the ruby script starts automatically and remains in running state.
exist any methods?
Thank you all for help

Comment: Is there a `]` at the end of your `CMD`? Also is it `Ruby` or `RUBY`, as is convention, at least for `ENV`?

Comment: You probably want to look at the `rails runner` command. [Docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#bin-rails-runner)

Comment: @tadman there is a ], i wronged when copied the code, and is "ruby", do you think that is the problem?

Comment: I just wonder what here is a legit typo and what is a copy-paste error. Where is `home` vs. `/home`

Comment: i just modify the code, another paste error, I wrote this code on ubuntu vm and i write this answer on windows

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a rake task https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/command_line.html#custom-rake-tasks

Create your own task and run it with rails cli, like

```bash
/path/to_your_app/bin/rails task_namespace:task_name
```

But you need to have your rails app dockerized too in the same container